# 74HC4046 VCO sensitivity

Tags: integrated-circuit, pll

I am currently working with 74HC4046 IC. I want to know (calculate) what is the VCO sensitivity (in Hz/V) when Phase Detector 1 is used. I have the datasheet but I am not sure how to make the calculation. Any ideas?

Comment: The choice of phase detector is unrelated to the VCO's sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

The sensitivity is adjustable using external components (mainly R1).  Have a look at the VCO_in vs f_out graphs in the datasheet.

Comment: How about the formulas on page 2 here:

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4046A_CNV.pdf

I know they are for the HCT version, but could they be relevant to the question (I see we have different equations for PD1, PD2 and PD3)?

Comment: Also, do these graphs correspond to some equation or are they only measured?

Comment: @Martin Those formulae aren't relevant.